# Mule WSProxyService throws exceptions

Tags: mule

An almost out of the box example, [https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/proxying-web-services#wsproxyservice]
 throws the following error: What am I missing?

- When issue a SoapUI xml request 
  org.mule.component.ComponentException: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{HttpWebServiceBridge.component.193834439}. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
- When I issue a WSDL get request
  org.mule.component.ComponentException: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{HttpWebServiceBridge.component.1639543744}. Message payload is of type: NullPayload

> ```
> <spring:beans>
>     <spring:bean name="WSProxyService" class="org.mule.module.cxf.WSProxyService">
>         <spring:property name="wsdlFile" value="schema/calculator.wsdl"/>
>     </spring:bean>
> </spring:beans>
>
> <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
> <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/> 
>
> <flow name="HttpWebServiceBridge">
>     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/calc" doc:name="HTTP" />
>     <component >
>         <spring-object bean="WSProxyService" />
>      </component>
>     <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.listener.path']" method="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.method']" doc:name="HTTP"/>
> </flow>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the example would not work - See this jira - [JIRA](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5870)

To answer your question, please use the below flow with the CXF tags to get your result.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="http://www.dneonline.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="calculator.asmx">

    </http:request-config>
    <cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/> 

<flow name="HttpWebServiceBridge">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/calc" doc:name="HTTP" />
   <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="calculator.wsdl"
   service="Calculator" configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" doc:name="CXF" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" payload="body" port="CalculatorSoap"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis I appreciate your time.